# Cannot install modules with anaconda installed

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, module, anaconda

I installed `anaconda` a little while ago. Later I installed `django`. `Django` was the first program I could install successfully and run without error.

I just tried to install `mysqldb` with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

and it gave following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-mysqldb is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
linux-headers-3.5.0-17 linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

If I run a `django` app configure to have a `mysql` back-end I get

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

I think this has something to do with having anaconda installed. I'm running on `ubuntu` OS.

Does anyone know how I can get `mysqldb` module to get recognized by `django`?

**It looks like all my anaconda modules are in:**

```
/home/aiden/anaconda/lib/python2.7
```

**I think my django lives in:**

/home/aiden/django/

**and i searched for mysqldb and found a file under anaconda:**

```
/home/aiden/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/something.../drizzle/mysqldb.py
```

I don't know how to check where I installed things to, but I think that `mysqldb` isn't getting installed b/c it's already somewhere in `anaconda`

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get` is going to install things into the system Python. To install things into Anaconda, you need to use the `conda` package manager, assuming the package is build for conda already, or else build from source. You can also try to find the package on binstar.org if there isn't one in conda already.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a "conda install bottle" but it didn't have the package available, but it automatically installed bottle using pip. This works fine. Anaconda is great.