# Why I can not use an installed module for python?

Tags: python, mysql, linux

I have installed a python library MySQLdb, and it works yesterday. But today when I tried to run it, it goes on as following:

```
czhao@opx790:~$ python
Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun  2 2014, 12:34:02) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

It is really strange, so I try to re-install it, but it seems I do have the library in my computer:

```
czhao@opx790:~$ sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
[sudo] password for czhao: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-mysqldb is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgooglepinyin0-dev linux-headers-3.2.0-27 linux-headers-3.2.0-41
  linux-headers-3.2.0-37 linux-headers-3.2.0-43 linux-headers-3.2.0-61
  patchutils linux-headers-3.2.0-37-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-27-generic
  linux-headers-3.2.0-61-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-43-generic dpatch
  linux-headers-3.2.0-41-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
```

I do not know why, I have the library but python keep tell me I do not have it.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get purge python-mysqldb; sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`?

Comment: Try installing with pip, `pip install MySQL-python`

Comment: Since you're using Anaconda, you should look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150416/cannot-install-modules-with-anaconda-installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Anaconda Python, but the package installed with `apt-get` was installed for the system Python. These two different distributions have different library directories, so packages/modules installed with one are not available for the other.

To get around this, use the `pip` program that came with Anaconda and run `sudo pip install MySQL-python`.

Comment: it is `pip install MySQL-python`.